# React native application crashing in device at launch time. Working fine in simulater

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I have created one react native app and successfully run in simulator. But it is crashing at launch time in device.

crash log added below. please check it out and help

Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.View.propTypes.style')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.View.prop..., stack:

Comment: what is your command? just `react-native run-android` ?

Comment: importing PropTypes from `react` has been deprecated in `React 16`, I would check all the libraries you're using in your `package.json` for any issues on their github pages.

Comment: these are i am using

"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.17.1",
  "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
  "react-native": "0.49.3",
  "react-native-collapsible": "^0.9.0",
  "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.5.1",
  "react-native-dash": "0.0.7",

Comment: "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
  "react-native-elements": "^0.17.0",
  "react-native-form-validator": "^0.2.0",
  "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.5.0",
  "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
  "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "redux-persist": "^5.5.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "rm": "^0.1.8",
  "validate.js": "^0.12.0"
 },

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by an component issue, to fix it go to the component .js and make this changes

```
import React,{
    PropTypes
} from 'react';
```

to

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

them find all `View.propTypes.style` and change to `ViewPropTypes.style`

Comment: can you give me the path where i can find this file - component.js ?

Comment: what i mean is there's a component in your application  who have an proptypes issue, you need to debug it to find, i recommend search in your application for .js files with `View.propTypes.style`